# JPA getSingleResult - EntityNotfound Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am trying to fetch a java entity through JPA getSingleResult but its throwing an exception I could not find in the [API specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult())

Method:

```
public static Object getSingleResultOrNull(Query q){
        try{
            return q.getSingleResult();
        }catch(NoResultException| EntityNotFoundException enfex){
            System.out.println(enfex.getMessage());
            enfex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }catch(NonUniqueResultException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Calling code:

```
tagName = tagName.trim().toLowerCase();
Tags tag = (Tags) getSingleResultOrNull(namedQuery("Tags.findByName")
                                        .setParameter("name", tagName));
```

Tag class:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "tags") @XmlRootElement @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Tags.findByName", query = "SELECT t FROM Tags t WHERE t.name = :name")}) 
public class Tags implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

**Edit :** Adding ProductTags. class

```
public class ProductTags implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "created")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdated;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "last_updated_by")
    private String lastUpdatedBy;
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product prod;
    @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Tags tag;
```

As per API spec for getSingleResult, only the following exceptions should be thrown:

- `NoResultException` - if there is no result
- `NonUniqueResultException` - if more than one result
- `IllegalStateException` - if called for a Java Persistence query
  language UPDATE or DELETE statement
- `QueryTimeoutException` - if the
  query execution exceeds the query timeout value set and only the
  statement is rolled back
- `TransactionRequiredException` - if a lock
  mode has been set and there is no transaction
- `PessimisticLockException` - if pessimistic locking fails and the
  transaction is rolled back
- `LockTimeoutException` - if pessimistic
  locking fails and only the statement is rolled back
- `PersistenceException` - if the query execution exceeds the query
  timeout value set and the transaction is rolled back

However, I am getting a strange exception of javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [models.ProductTags#]

for a totally (not totally as ProductTags has a foreign key of Tags object, but in context of saving Tags object, I don't see any relation.) unrelated entity.

> deleted entity passed to persist: [models.ProductTags#]
>   javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to
>   persist: [models.ProductTags#]  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1369)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:307)
>     at
>   controllers.PowerController.getSingleResultOrNull(PowerController.java:68)
>     at
>   controllers.ProductController.updateProductInfo(ProductController.java:282)
>     at
>   router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:1584)
>     at
>   router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:1584)
>     at
>   play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
>     at
>   play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127)
>     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:70)     at
>   play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20)
>     at interceptors.ProductAction.call(ProductAction.java:65)   at
>   play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.lambda$call$5(TransactionalAction.java:19)
>     at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$$Lambda$43/469822182.apply(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:136)     at
>   play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:159)     at
>   play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:16)     at
>   play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)  at
>   play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)  at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
>     at
>   play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
>     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:485)  at
>   play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)     at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
>     at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
>     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)     at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104)
>     at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103)
>     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)   at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103)  at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)   at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:537)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:537)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)    at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

I am aware of another way to write the getSingleResultOrNull method but I am not able to find the problem in this case.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating `Query` object that you are passing to `getSingleResultOrNull(...)` method. I doubt you might be using a `session` that already has some pending updates. Can you creating query from new session using `openSession(...)` method of `SessionFactory` and try..

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is caused in some step before. Looking at your stack trace, there's this line just before calling the method you show:

```
controllers.ProductController.updateProductInfo(ProductController.java:282)
```

Maybe you are updating the state of some object inside **updateProductInfo** and Hibernate is flushing the session just when you call **getSingleResultOrNull** method.

Here there's some similar situation that you can also take a look at: [Deleted entity passed to persist exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178304/deleted-entity-passed-to-persist-exception)

Comment: Hi @bruno.zambiazi, thanks for your inputs. I don't have any cascading for the relationship, so ideally when I am removing a productTag, it should leave my product and tag classed untouched. Updating the code in question for this. Also the line you are referring to just calls the method I have shown here. And I am removing a few entities of Product tags in teh updateProductInfo before this method call, nothing else. Please see if the additional class definition in the question helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when I query for a Entity that exists but which isn't in the database:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
```